# Creating an array from table data and currently getting empty strings in the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, razor

I have a table where the owner is meant to enter details:

```
<table id="ownerDetailsTable" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of Contact Name</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of Contact Title</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of contact email</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableToModify">
                        <tr id="1">

                            <td>

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterventionOwnerName, new { @class = "form-control element-one", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Name", value = "" })
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterverntionOwnerTitle, new { @class = "form-control element-two", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Title", value = "" })
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterventionOwnerEmail, new { @class = "form-control element-three", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Email", value = "" })
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input id="addRow" , type="button" onclick="createRow(); getOwnerDetails()" value="Add Point of Contact" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Currently, on click, a new row of inputs is created and the details entered by the user are meant to go into an array:

```
<script>
        var ownerDetailArray = [];
        function getOwnerDetails() {
            $('table#ownerDetailsTable tr').each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('input');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () {
                        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text())
                    });
                    ownerDetailArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
                console.log(ownerDetailArray);
            });
        }
```

The array is being created but the strings in the array - which should be the info entered by the user - are empty. I feel as though the issue in the way that I am attempting to find the data and push it into the array. Any help/advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get input value , then change `arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text())` to `arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).val());`
I assume your `@Html.TextBoxFor` creates `<input />` tag.

```js
        var ownerDetailArray = [];
        function getOwnerDetails() {
            $('table#ownerDetailsTable tr').each(function () {
                var arrayOfThisRow = [];
                var tableData = $(this).find('input');
                if (tableData.length > 0) {
                    tableData.each(function () {
                        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    ownerDetailArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
                }
                console.log(ownerDetailArray);
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ownerDetailsTable" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of Contact Name</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of Contact Title</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold">HP Point of contact email</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableToModify">
                        <tr id="1">

                            <td>
<input class = "form-control element-one", maxlength="250", placeholder = "Owner Name", value = ""/>
                                <@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterventionOwnerName, new { @>class = "form-control element-one", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Name", value = "" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
<input class = "form-control element-one", maxlength="250", placeholder = "Owner Name", value = ""/>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterverntionOwnerTitle, new { @class = "form-control element-two", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Title", value = "" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
<input class = "form-control element-one", maxlength="250", placeholder = "Owner Name", value = ""/>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterventionOwnerEmail, new { @class = "form-control element-three", @maxlength = 250, placeholder = "Owner Email", value = "" })
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input id="addRow" , type="button" onclick="getOwnerDetails()" value="Add Point of Contact" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was trying to get it with '.value' which was sort of correct but this has fixed. Now to fix the way the arrays are returned.

Comment: @MatthewWright   `.value` is for plain javascript. Since you are using Jquery, you want to use `val()`. Either one works, but you want to keep the consistency in your code.